# Filling geodesic triangles by geodesic segments

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesics

Let $ M $ be a [Hadamard manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_manifold). For every $ x,y\in M $,
define $[x,y]$ to be the geodesic segment connecting $ x $ to $ y $, as a subset of $ M $.

> Let $ x,y,z\in M $ be arbitrary and consider $p\in [x,y]$. Let $a\in[p,z] $. Is
>   there an element $q\in [y,z]$ such that $ a\in[q,x]$?

In other words, we have one geodesic triangle with different vertices  $x,y,z$, but filled with geodesic segments in three different way. We are interested in whether the obtained sets are the same or not? If not, provide a counterexample. Or under what conditions is this equality correct? For the special case  $ \mathbb{R}^n $, this is trivial.

I am not very familiar with the tools and notions in this area, so I don't know how to prove or disprove it.

---

**Update:**
The assumption of the question is changed to Hadamard manifolds so that every pair of points is connected by a unique geodesic segment.

In regard to comments, I am now interested to know **under what conditions this equality is correct.**

Comment: there might not be a unique geodesic segment. For $y$ inside the injectivity radius of $x$ there is however. Also I think it should be possible to prove your claim for $[y,z]$ is contained in the injectivity radius.

Comment: It would surprise me if this were true -- in a manifold of dimension 3 or more, two 1-dimensional submanifolds (such as the two geodesics $[y,z]$ and $[q,x]$) do not generically intersect.

Comment: No. Otherwise filling the triangle with geodesic segments $[z,p]$ or with  segments $[x,q]$ or with  segments $[y,r]$ would produce the same surface. (If some two of these surfaces do not coincide, then one finds a counterexample to your conjecture by permuting $x, y, z$.) But if all three fillings coincide, then the surface contains three geodesics through each point. Then the second fundamental form vanishes, and the surface is geodesic. But if your manifold is not a space form, then there are three points not in one geodesic surface. The simplest example is $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev Does the above argument require assuming non-positive curvature? Or would it go through with only the assumptions of Hopf-Rinow? (Sorry for the stupid question, I am deeply ignorant of Riemannian geometry, as you can probably tell.)